# In IntelliJ, how can I speed up "resolve reference"?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Ctrl+clicking a method and resolving the reference can easily take ten seconds

[image]

And it does eventually succeed.

How can I speed it up?

Notes:

- Heap: 4GB
- The project is stored on an SSD.
- The CPU should be more than fast enough.
- Files are excluded from antivirus.

Link: [CPU snapshot made with VisualVM.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dc3p1artjvogpfa/snapshot.nps?dl=0)

Comment: Buy an SSD, fast Intel CPU and exclude IntelliJ and project files from an antivirus. Or give us more details... Or report an issue https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241235-Reporting-performance-problems

Comment: What details do you want?

Comment: Do you have enough heap? You can use VisualVM to sample CPU, that could tell you where is the problem..

Comment: Is .IntelliJIdea2017.1 folder excluded as well?

Comment: 200MB of free heap is tragically low... Check in VisualVM if GC is eating your CPU.

Comment: We can guess forever until you provide [the CPU snapshot](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241235).

Comment: Increasing heap to 4GB did not help. Looking into CPU snapshot now.

Comment: OK, I took a a CPU snapshot. Where does IntelliJ store that? The documentation doesn't say (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241235).

Comment: @Meo: I've made a snapshot with VisualVM. Link added to the post.

Comment: So you are using Scala... perhaps this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-10035  or report a new one

Comment: Perhaps. I'll try that and see what happens.